# PHP like languages that offers embedded HTML

Tags: php, html

What are the other languages that has the ability to handle embedded HTML/Non-processed-text like PHP's `<?php /*PHP CODE*/ ?> NON-PHP CODE` **natively** ?

What I actually want is to keep the logic part hard coded may be in C++ then I'll expose the constructs like few variables for the presentation layer to work with it. and leave the presentation part loose on some scripting language where I can embed a mark up language. as the presentation layer is supposed to be rapidly changing there won't be a compilation overhead ..

Comment: I would offer an alternative to this requirement: **separation of your business and display logic**.

Comment: @rdlowrey, keep in mind that this can be done without moving to a language that has no embed-able nature and must rely on additional libraries.

Comment: @rdlowrey sure you should separate the *logic*, but there's nothing wrong with using embedded code to display something you processed with the controller/model

Comment: @Xeoncross I totally agree. I <3 PHP. When possible I try to get people thinking about generating HTML in a more semantically appropriate fashion than a mish-mash of html and server-side code. Same goes for Alex ... I agree, but if the OP needs to ask this question, how likely is it that he/she/it is planning to implement, say, a templating engine in the language they settle on? It's much likelier that ease of use is the goal.

Comment: @NeelBasu: You can write binary extensions for PHP and then use PHP to make use of them *and* having the embedding that PHP already offers. Otherwise maybe python (via django) or perl is useful as it has a good integration of binary modules as well.

Comment: @hakre Thats what I am doing. however I am having a look on other alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Popular server technologies supporting embedded HTML:**

- [Active Server Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa286483.aspx) *(.asp)*
- [Embedded Ruby Files](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) *(.erb)*
- [Groovy Server Pages](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp) *(.gsp)*
- [JavaServer Pages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html)  *(.jsp)*
- [PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) *(.php)*

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Examples) for a more complete list.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails does (with `.erb` - embedded ruby files) - you can use embedded ruby in the views for rails MVC applications...

For example:

```
<p>
<b>Some HTML</b>
<%= puts "some ruby" %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP does as well, though I would not recommend using it for a modern project.

Answer (score 0):

**JSP (Java Server Page)**, **classic ASP** and **Ruby on rails** are some PHP like server side programming languages for working in the web applications

Answer (score 0):

X(HT)ML has this natively with [processing instructions (XML 1.0; 8 Dec 1997)](http://www.w3.org/TR/PR-xml-971208#sec-pi):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><!-- a processing instruction -->
<html>
  <head><?pi /* instructions here */ ?></head><!-- another one -->
  <body><?pi /* instructions there */ ?></body>
  <?php /* even this is a valid processing instruction */ ?>
</html>
```

Apart from that which is merely informative and depends on the processor as well, you find similar stuff with many web related languages like:

- Java - [JSP - JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)
- Lua - [haserl](http://haserl.sourceforge.net/)
- Microsoft Basic - [ASP - Active Server Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages)
- Perl - [Embperl](http://perl.apache.org/embperl/)
- PHP - [PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor](http://php.net/)
- Ruby - [eruby - Embedded Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/web.html#S2)

And many, many more.