# Are there other programming than PHP, ASP.NET and JSP that can be execute with a tag without using any template engine?

Tags: java, php, asp.net, jsp

Are there other programming languages than PHP, ASP.NET and Java/JSP that can be declared with just a tag to execute in a natural way, without using any template engine?

Example for PHP:

```
<h1>Today is <?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>!</h1>
```

For ASP.NET:

```
<h1>Today is <%response.write(date())%>!</h1>
```

For JSP:

```
<h1>Today is <%= new java.util.Date() %>!</h1>
```

Comment: I'm asking for languages that offers embedded HTML without using any template engine..

Comment: Define 'template engine' please. Because in your question heading it mentions "with a tag".

Comment: @Servant: Did you read the answers on the linked question? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024275/1438393), in specific.

Comment: @robnick Such as: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/

Comment: I think there's no other programming than PHP, ASP.NET and JSP that offers embedded HTML without using any template engine..

Comment: @Servant: You know what your answer is.

Comment: @Ravinder I'm not sure that's why I'm asking..

Comment: @Servant: See your comment *I think there's no ... without template*.  And that is the answer for your question.